# NServiceBus.Logging failing with $ character

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I am trying to implement logging feature in NServiceBus with .Net Framework 4.6.1 with C#. The library for NServiceBus is NServiceBus.Core.

I am getting compilation error as "Unexpected character $"

```
log.Info($"Handling: OrderPlaced for Order Id: {message.OrderId}");
```

Need to read the message.OrderId properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the only place where string interpolation does not work in your project? Does this code compile?

```
var str = $"{1}";
```

If not, you should check your language level in project settings:

[image: 1]

It should be set to C# 6.0 or higher.